# Gemfire - How to restrict/limit OQL queries for a region

Tags: gemfile, gemfire, oql

Some users are executing OQL for regions that are triggering out of memory errors in a huge region. Sorting a query alone triggers an out of memory error.

Is there any configuration to weather restrict the memory footprint or forbid queries for a specific region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are not specific ways to restrict memory consumption only for queries.

There are, however, other options that you can use to make the cluster more resilient to these situations (aside from the obvious one: educate your users to not execute things like `SELECT *` on huge regions):

1. Configure the [Geode Resource Manager](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/managing/heap_use/heap_management.html), which allows Geode to automatically cancel running queries whenever the memory is above a pre-configured threshold (see [here](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/developing/querying_basics/monitor_queries_for_low_memory.html)).
2. Deploy a custom `SecurityManager` for authentication and authorization, and assign `DATA:READ:RegionName` permissions sparingly to your users. When security is enabled, users trying to execute `OQL` queries against a particular `RegionName` are required to have the `DATA:READ:RegionName` [ResourcePermission](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/managing/security/implementing_authorization.html) assigned, so you can decide before hand to whom give this privileges. More details [here](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/managing/security/chapter_overview.html).

Comment: Thank you Juan!  Your two options are great! I was considering Monitoring Low Memory When Querying but I'm not really sure about it as it can degrade performance as it needs to keep track of query sizes.

Comment: Enabling the `ResourceManager` shouldn't impact the performance of your cluster, I've seen it used in several production environments. As a side note, it doesn't only protect your cluster from undiscriminated queries, but also from burst of activities that might bring members down during peak times... I strongly recommend enabling it!. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Juan! I'd love to give you more points for the answer.  One of the top answers in stackoverflow.